# Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file in ubuntu

Tags: android, ionic-framework, appium

I am trying to capture the snapshot using ui automator view but when i try to take the snap shot i am getting the following error:

```
Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file.
```

Even i have tried to restart the device multiple times as well but still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: can you please do couple of things like, 1. unlpug and plug the device to the system. 2. And restart the appium server. let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @SurajJogdand Did the same but still i am facing the issue

Comment: Whenever you open the uiautomatorviewer, please make ensure that the Appium server is not running in background.

Comment: @SnehaShinde I have checked it but the server is not running

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening automator using "uiautomatorviewer" Paste this in your terminal. It will open the correct Autmator

```
Android/Sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer
```